# A necessary and sufficent condition for $|x|^{-\alpha}/(|\log(2/|x|)|)$ to be in $L^p(\mathbb R^d)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Consider the function
$$f_0(x) =  \begin{cases} 
      |x|^{-\alpha}/(\log(2/|x|) & |x|<1 \\
      0 &  |x|\geq 1
   \end{cases}
$$
We aim to determine a necessary and sufficient condition on $\alpha$ for $f_0(x) \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$. My approach has been as follows:

Using the integration formula for polar coordinates of the Lebesgue integral we have
$$\|f_0\|_{L^p}^p = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f_0|^p dm(x) = \int_{|x|<1} \frac{|x|^{-p\alpha}}{|\log(2/|x|)|^p} dm(x)  = \int_{S^{d-1}}\Big( \int_{0}^1\frac{r^{-p\alpha}}{\log(2/r)^p} r^{d-1} dr\Big) d\sigma(\gamma)$$
$$=(-1)^p \int_{S^{d-1}}\Big( \int_0^1 \frac{r^{d-1-p\alpha}}{\log(r/2)^p}dr\Big) d \sigma(\gamma)$$
where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure, $r = |x|$ and $\gamma = \frac{x}{|x|}$. If this is the right idea for this proof, I can't quite see how to proceed. Is there an easier way to tackle this problem that I'm just not seeing?

For reference, this is Exercise 1.1 in Stein and Shakarchi's [Functional Analysis](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1235.46001).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right method. You don't want to take $(-1)^p$ out because $\log(r/2)<0$ for $0<r<1$. Quick sketch: set $l=\log1/r$, then
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{r^{d-1-p\alpha}}{|\log2 + \log(1/r)|^p}dr = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-(d-p\alpha) l}}{|\log2+l|^p} dl $$
This is always integrable at $0$ so you only need to consider the behaviour at infinity. You should find integrable if $d>p\alpha$, or $d=p\alpha$ and $p>1$; divergent otherwise.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you so much!

Comment: @slowspider sorry there was a typo, it should be $d=p\alpha$ and $p>1$ (the dimension of the $l$ integral is 1)